# Is a $G$-invariant character $\theta$ of $H$ extendible to $G$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

Let $G/H\cong PSL(2,11)$, and $\theta$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-character of $H$. Suppose $\theta$ is invariant in $G$ and $\theta(1)=9$.

> Question: Is $\theta$ extendible to $G$?

Comment: I take it that $\theta (1)=9$ is a typo?

Comment: @Venkataramana $\theta(1)$ is the degree of $\theta$.

Comment: it would be very strange if this was true. look for counterexamples...

Comment: By [Clifford theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_theory), some multiple of $\theta$ extends to $G$.

Comment: Silly question- Does $PSL(2,11)$ mean the projective group of rank 1 over $\mathbb F_{11}$ or the projective group of rank $10$ over $\mathbb F_{2}$?

Comment: @ kneidell  $PSL(2,11)$  means the projective group of rank 1 over $F_{11}$.

Comment: @Simon: Ok, so I think you can use Theorem 11.15 of Isaac's book ''Character theory of finite groups'' to prove extendibility. Write down the defining relation of the cocycle associated to $\theta$, take determinants, and use what the theorem tells you about the order of this cocycle.

Comment: Oh, wait.. I'm not sure what I suggested would work here.

Comment: @kneidell  I know that Theorem 11.15.  But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but it's what I had in mind- the assumption $\theta(1)=9$ implies that $\det(\rho_\theta(h))$ is a $3^k$ root of unity for some $k$. Here $\rho_\theta$ is a representation affording $\theta$. Using the defining relation of the cocycle $\beta\in H^2(G/H,\mathbb C)$ associated with $\theta$, it is possible to infer that $\beta$ must have order $3^k$ as well, but by the theorem is should also divide $|PSL(2,11)|=1320$, and hence is either $1$ or $3$. Maybe there's some reason why it can't be $3$? (IDK)

Comment: The order of $PSL(2,11)$ is, of course, $660$, and not $1320$. I can't edit for some reason.. anyway, it doesn't affect the (non-) argument.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is yes (and some of the comments were moving in the right direction): Let $T$ be a transversal to $H$ in $G,$ and let $\sigma$ afford the representation of $H.$ For each $t \in T,$ there is a matrix $M_{t} \in {\rm GL}(9,\mathbb{C})$ such that $\sigma(tht^{-1}) = M_{t}\sigma(h)M_{t}^{-1}$ for all $h \in H,$ and $M_{t}$ is unique up to scalar multiples (by Schur's Lemma) , while any non-zero scalar multiple will have the same property. Extend this to $G$ by letting $M_{th} = M_{t}\sigma(h)$ for each $t \in T, h \in H.$
(It might be convenient here for anyone interested in full detail, to assume that have multiplied $\sigma$ by a  suitable power of the linear character $ \lambda = {\rm det} \sigma,$ so that ${\rm det} \sigma$ may be assumed to have multiplicative order a power of $3$).

Note also that for $x,y \in G,$ there is a scalar $\alpha(x,y) \neq 0$ such that $M_{xy} = \alpha(x,y)M_{x}M_{y} (\ast).$

Notice then $M_{x}^{|G|}$ is a scalar matrix for each $x \in G.$ Multiplying each $M_{x}$ by a suitable scalar (and we can still keep $M_{h} = \sigma(h)$ for each $h \in H$, and $M_{th} = M_{t}\sigma(h)$ for $t \in T,h \in H$), we may, and do from now on, assume that each $M_{x}$ has determinant a $3$-power root of unity.

It follows from $(\ast)$ (on taking determinants), that $\alpha(x,y)$ is a $3$-power root of unity for all $x,y \in G.$ This gives a $2$-cocycle for ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$ of $3$-power order.

Now we can finish in either of two ways: the Schur multiplier of the perfect group ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$ is well-known to have order $2.$ But a more general argument is to note that a perfect group with a cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup always has a Schur multiplier of order prime to $p$ ( and this may be applied here with $p =3$ ).

Comment: Firstly, Thanks.     But, I don't understand: (1) why $M_t$ is a scalar; (2) why could we multiply each $M_t$ by a suitable scalar in paragraph two.

Comment: Now, I understand the proof.   I think that we  don’t have to prove " $M_t$  is a root of unity multiple of $σ(t^{660})$  and that each$ M_t$ has finite multiplicative order."  Can you give me some reasons?  @Geoff Robinson

Comment: Maybe there is a problem.  Let $t,s\in T$.  However, I am not sure $st\in T$.  And, if we consider a linear character $\theta\in Irr(H)$, this proof should be effective. It means that every $G$-invariant linear character  is  extendible to $G$.

Comment: Now, I understand that $\alpha(x,y)$  gives a  $2$-cocycle for $G$. I don't understand that $\alpha(x,y)$  gives  a $2$-cocycle for $G/H\cong PSL(2,11)$. I hope you give me the reason. Thank you, again.

Comment: We have constructed a central extension of $G$ by a finite cyclic $3$-group. This is $\{ (\omega^{i}, M_{g}): g \in G :0 \leq i \leq 3^{m}-1)$ where $omega$ is some primitive $3^{m}$-th of unity. It has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $\sigma(H),$ which is $\{(1,\sigma(h)): h \in H \}.$ When we factor out the latter normal subgroup, we get a central extension of ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$ by a cyclic group of order $3^{m}.$